# mail command no longer reads from /var/spool/mail/root

Tags: email, postfix

Until half an hour ago `mail` command worked as expected.

Now it says `no mail for root`.

But I can still see and read my mail in `/var/spool/mail/root`.

I don't believe I've changed any settings. I'm using postfix 2.10 if that is relevant.

**Update 1**
Output of `echo "testing" | postfix -v root@localhost`

```
postfix: name_mask: all
postfix: name_mask: subnet
postfix: inet_addr_local: configured 2 IPv4 addresses
postfix: inet_addr_local: configured 2 IPv6 addresses
postfix: been_here: 127.0.0.0/8: 0
postfix: been_here: 172.30.0.0/24: 0
postfix: been_here: [::1]/128: 0
postfix: been_here: [fe80::]/64: 0
postfix: mynetworks: 127.0.0.0/8 172.30.0.0/24 [::1]/128 [fe80::]/64 
postfix/postfix-script: error: unknown command: 'root@localhost'
postfix/postfix-script: fatal: usage: postfix start (or stop, reload, abort, flush, check, status, set-permissions, upgrade-configuration)
```

**Update 2**
**The werid thing now is that `mail` works, but reads from `centos` rather than `root`**

I don't want to paste the aliases file because the only way I know how to format it here will take me forever.
BUT, after running the `cat` command, at the bottom of the output I see `You have mail in /var/spool/mail/centos`. Which I don't see when I open the file with `vim`.

Comment: What does `echo "testing" | postfix -v root@localhost` say?

Comment: How about `cat /etc/aliases` now?

Comment: You sure there wasn't a security update that got applied?

Comment: Yes. I think I'm starting to get a clue. It might be that the DNS records have finally started to propagate properly. (changed them recently)

Comment: I face the same question. The `mail -u root` works, while `mail` shows "No mail for root". It dues to `su` command, and `su -` works.

Comment: if only i could remember how i solved this